# Are C# 'using system.X' imports compiled when built or pulled from a system DLL when run?

Tags: c#, dll, compilation, dllimport

If they are pulled from a system DLL(Like the C/C++ send function), is it possible to identify which one httpClient functions are located in?

Comment: "using" keyword has nothing to do with dll. It only deals with namespaces. The same namespace may exist in one or many assemblies/dll. But in terms of assembly loading, they are pulled during rumtime. You can decompile the dll and take a look

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the using keyword. Is it possible to locate the dll that httpClient functions are found in? Similar to how the send function in C/C++ is found in the ws2_32.dll

Comment: No, not really.  The framework uses a lot of pinvoke with [DllImport] to get its job done.  You'd have to know enough about the winapi plumbing to know [to look for WSASend](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=wsasend).  Or ask at SO, I guess.  There does need to be a point to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` is in fact just a syntax simplifier. It allows

```
using System;
..
String foo = "hello";
```

instead of

```
System.String foo = "hello";
```

nothing fancy

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the using keyword. So httpClient functions are in a dll and called at runtime. Is it possible to locate the dll that httpClient functions are found in? Similar to how the send function in C/C++ is found in the ws2_32.dll

Comment: open object browser window and search for the class. Or look on msdn - it tells you what dll each class is in

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object for Httpclient.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient ()
```

Right click on HttpClient and Go to definition.
It will tell the name of namespace as well as pre-compiled assembly inside tools like visual studio.

Comment: (Apologies, flagged as not an answer due to misreading the question - which is pretty oddly phrased.) Although I generally prefer looking up the docs...